# How do I configure lynx to pass images to xloadimage, xv or zvg?

Tags: x11, lynx

I know that it's possible to configure `lynx` to pass images (PNG/GIF/JPEG/JPG) to `xloadimage`, `xv` or `zvg` and I've looked online ([Description of lynx configuration](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.5/lynx_help/body.html); [Use lynx with browser image support](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/22/lynx-browser-with-image-support-x11/) ; [Lynx with HTML Images](http://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/manDOCS/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html#Images)) for documentation for how to do this, to no avail. I've tried changing/adding directives to lynx's configuration file (`lynx.cfg`), without success. What is the correct configuration for images? Do I need to compile `lynx` from source and, if so, what flags/parameters do I need to specify? Should I rather use Netscape Navigator/Communicator (as that seems to support images without configuration)?

Comment: If you want image support for a terminal-based browser, go with w3m. Its image support is mature, and its rendering is generally much better than lynx's. If you want an X11 browser, welcome to the 21st century, Netscape has long been replaced by Firefox.

Comment: I've tried `w3m`, but no luck. As for Firefox, I'm aware it replaced Netscape but don't know if it can be run from a plain X + window manager session without GTK/Qt?

Comment: What do you mean by “no luck”? Some distributions package w3m's image support separately (e.g. `w3m-img` in Debian). Firefox uses some Gtk libraries, but you can run any application with any window manager, or none at all for that matter.

Comment: I mean "no luck" as in "I installed `w3m-img` and the above-mentioned viewers, browsed to a page with an image on it and the image didn't display".

Comment: While the original question remains unanswered, I did manage to get Iceweasel (Firefox) working with `afterstep` on a Debian installation, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment, or add, [`XLOADIMAGE_COMMAND`](https://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.5/lynx_help/body.html#XLOADIMAGE_COMMAND) option in lynx.cfg, f.e.

```
XLOADIMAGE_COMMAND:xli -quiet %s &
```